# Is it possible to implement a 3D water/ocean layer in Mapbox GL?

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

For quite a while now, I've used three.js and their custom layer feature to place 3D objects within the Mapbox world (mostly on water). This works great, but the nicer the 3D models look, the less exciting seems the bland and monotonic water.

**Does anyone know whether it's possible to replace the water with a 3D scene, ideally with a nice ocean/wave/water shader? Has anyone done it?**

I know there are cool ocean shaders out there, but the main problem I have is that I can't get a 3D scene to cover just the water, and no land.

Mapbox seems to stack the layers (lowest first) like this:

- land (background)
- water
- more land features

So putting the 3D mesh "under" the land, places it under the water as well. And placing it over the water, places it over the land.

Here is a link to Mapbox's own example (making the shaders directly, no three.js): https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/

**Is there any way this example could be rewritten so that the 3D mesh is visible only over the water?**

[image: mapbox custom 3d layer]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. If you are able to find the Polygon or MultiPolygon that shapes the oceans.
I think you can make it with the full map size as a square as a polygon and then excluding the continents as defined by geoJson standard. And then you could be able to port [this shader](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=water#webgl_shaders_ocean)[image]

It could be a great addition for [Threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) too

Comment: Yes! This seems the be a workable approach. I found that my mapbox style uses water polygons from OpenStreetMap, but I've yet to understand how I could fetch these directly from somewhere.

Comment: Trying to fetch all the tiles could be painful, I thing the easiest approach would be to create a full rectangle and substract the geojson of all the continents from [here](https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/)

Comment: Were you able to make it run?

Comment: Not yet, no. I checked the continents and couldn't get good enough resolution from the data (the 10m version is far from what mapbox shows). Then I lost some time trying to implement the ocean shader in a customlayer and got frustrated with that also :D I did get the shader working, but something was very off with the lights/rendering.

Comment: If you can share any working repro of the shader I can probably assist with the resto of the Mapbox code. I’m maintaining [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) and this could be a great addition

Comment: I put together a simple version based on mapbox's customlayer example. This small example actually seems to work quite ok! So shader there, but limiting it to the water layer still the problem. (And welcome to the Finnish archipelago :)) https://github.com/mglonnro/mapbox-ocean

Comment: I'll take a look to it... I've been there due to work several times... too cold for a spaniard but beautiful indeed

Comment: Hey! I figured out something cool! If I add the elevated terrain stuff then mapbox will create that on top of the customlayer! Wohoo!